# Dynamic SQL Server stored procedure

Tags: sql-server

```
 ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[GetDocumentsAdvancedSearch]
          @SDI  CHAR(10) = NULL
             ,@Client CHAR(4) = NULL
             ,@AccountNumber VARCHAR(20) = NULL
         ,@Address VARCHAR(300)  = NULL
         ,@StartDate DATETIME = NULL
         ,@EndDate DATETIME = NULL
         ,@ReferenceID CHAR(14) = NULL
    AS
    BEGIN
      -- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
      -- interfering with SELECT statements.
      SET NOCOUNT ON;

      -- DECLARE
      DECLARE @Sql        NVARCHAR(4000)
      DECLARE @ParamList  NVARCHAR(4000)

      SELECT  @Sql = 'SELECT 
                        DISTINCT ISNULL(Documents.DocumentID, '') 
                       ,Person.Name1
                       ,Person.Name2
                       ,Person.Street1
                       ,Person.Street2
                       ,Person.CityStateZip
                       ,ISNULL(Person.ReferenceID,'')
                       ,ISNULL(Person.AccountNumber,'')
                       ,ISNULL(Person.HasSetPreferences,0)
                       ,Documents.Job
               ,Documents.SDI
                       ,Documents.Invoice
                       ,ISNULL(Documents.ShippedDate,'')
                       ,ISNULL(Documents.DocumentPages,'')
                       ,Documents.DocumentType
                       ,Documents.Description
                       FROM
                       Person
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN Documents ON Person.PersonID = Documents.PersonID
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN DocumentType ON Documents.DocumentType = DocumentType.DocumentType
                       LEFT OUTER JOIN Addressess   ON Person.PersonID = Addressess.PersonID'

       SELECT @Sql = @Sql + ' WHERE 
                       Documents.SDI IN ( '+ QUOTENAME(@sdi) + ') OR (Person.AssociationID = ' + ''' 000000 + ''' + 'AND Person.Client = ' + QUOTENAME(@Client)

        IF NOT (@AccountNumber IS  NULL)
        SELECT @Sql = @Sql + 'AND Person.AccountNumber LIKE' + QUOTENAME(@AccountNumber)
        IF NOT (@Address IS  NULL)
        SELECT @Sql = @Sql + 'AND Person.Name1 LIKE' +QUOTENAME(@Address)+ 'AND Person.Name2 LIKE' +QUOTENAME(@Address)+ 'AND Person.Street1 LIKE' +QUOTENAME(@Address)+ 'AND Person.Street2 LIKE' +QUOTENAME(@Address)+ 'AND Person.CityStateZip LIKE' +QUOTENAME(@Address)
        IF NOT (@StartDate IS  NULL)
        SELECT @Sql = @Sql + 'AND Documents.ShippedDate >=' +@StartDate
        IF NOT (@EndDate IS NULL)
        SELECT @Sql = @Sql + 'AND Documents.ShippedDate <=' +@EndDate
        IF NOT (@ReferenceID IS  NULL)
        SELECT @Sql = @Sql + 'AND Documents.ReferenceID =' +QUOTENAME(@ReferenceID)

        -- Insert statements for procedure here
       -- PRINT @Sql
        SELECT @ParamList = '@Psdi CHAR(10),@PClient CHAR(4),@PAccountNumber VARCHAR(20),@PAddress VARCHAR(300),@PStartDate DATETIME ,@PEndDate DATETIME,@PReferenceID CHAR(14)'  
        EXEC SP_EXECUTESQL @Sql,@ParamList,@Sdi,@Client,@AccountNumber,@Address,@StartDate,@EndDate,@ReferenceID
        --PRINT @Sql


    END
```

**ERROR**

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
>   Incorrect syntax near '000000'. Msg
>   105, Level 15, State 1, Line 23
>   Unclosed quotation mark after the
>   character string 'AND Person.Client =
>   [1   ]AND Person.AccountNumber
>   LIKE[1]'.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check out these lines of your statement:

```
'AND Person.AccountNumber LIKE' + QUOTENAME(@AccountNumber)
'AND Person.Name1 LIKE' +QUOTENAME(@Address)+ 'AND Person.Name2 LIKE' +QUOTENAME(@Address)+ 'AND Person.Street1 LIKE' +QUOTENAME(@Address)+ 'AND Person.Street2 LIKE' +QUOTENAME(@Address)+ 'AND Person.CityStateZip LIKE' +QUOTENAME(@Address)
```

This will result in something like

```
AND Person.AccountNumber LIKE[13123]AND Person.Name1 LIKE[bla]AND Person.Name2 LIKE[alskda]
```

and so forth - you need to start adding some spacing!

- put a space between your LIKE keyword and the value it's referring to:

  ```
   AND Person.AccountNumber LIKE ''' + @AccountNumber + '''' +
  ```
- put a space before every AND in your statements

  ```
   SELECT @Sql = @Sql + ' AND Person.Name1 LIKE ''' + @Address + 
                 ''' AND Person.Name2 LIKE ''' + @Address + 
                 ''' AND Person.Street1 LIKE ''' + @Address + 
                 ''' AND Person.Street2 LIKE '  ........
  ```

Comment: hey marc, i made the changes and it's working fine now. thanks so much.Appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Just stop using [`QUOTENAME`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms176114.aspx) for your values. It's not supposed to be used for that.

**EDIT**
You also have several `AND`s where there is not space in front. Make sure to add spaces so that you don't get something like `bla=0AND` ...

Comment: @Pinu: well, you still need to quote your string values. But with proper single quotes and not the brackets (`[]`) added by QUOTENAME