# Incorrect syntax near 'case', 'when' and 'end' in CASE statement

Tags: sql, sql-server-2012, logic, sql-function

I been running into errors in my case statement. Right now I am testing it against NorthWind DB before I use it in a project that I am involved in. 
I know I should be using IF/ELSE, and it works with the IF/ELSE, only problem is that I have to do this in a function and not use a stored procedure.
From my understanding is that I have to use a case statement when using a tablevalued function, because functions can only contain be one statement so a case needs to be used and I was told that what I was doing with the IF/ELSE is that functions don't allow that type of logic..

I'll be passing an ID along with the @PreAQ and its only going to return records based on filters that will be like the ones seen below, but with multiple LIKES.

```
declare @PreAQ int
set @PreAQ = 0

case 
when @PreAQ = 0
    then
        (select * from Contacts where CompanyName like 'An%')
when @PreAQ = 1 
    then 
        (select * from Contacts where ContactTitle like 'S%')
end
```

The errors being thrown are

> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'case'.
>
> Msg 156, Level 15, State 1, Line 11
>   Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'when'.
>
> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 14
>   Incorrect syntax near 'end'.

I have also tried...

```
case @PreAQ
when  = 0
    then...
```

and then I get the same errors

**EDIT**

Here is something similar to what my function will be doing at work (other than the filters are different and the table, but this is still using the NorthWind as a test DB, notice how depending on the '@PreAQ' number, I need it run the statement. I'm trying to do this...

```
declare @PreAQ int
set @PreAQ = 0

case
when @PreAq 0
    then
(select * from [Contacts]
where (CompanyName like 'An%' 
or CompanyName like 'B%'
or CompanyName like 'Ch%'
or CompanyName like 'De%'
or CompanyName like 'F%'))

 when @PreAQ 1
then
 (select * from [Contacts]
 where (CompanyName like 'Wa%' 
or CompanyName like 'Be%'
or CompanyName like 'Y%'
or CompanyName like 'DeF%'
or CompanyName like 'Fa%'
or CompanyName like 'Me%'
or CompanyName like 'Ma%'))
 end
```

Comment: Think about it: with functions, you know the returned table structure in advance. How could that work if you were allowed to return from two different tables with different structures depending on a parameter?

Comment: @hvd, you are correct. I made an edit so its coming from the same table. That should clear up any misunderstanding. In the project it will be using a specific table, now the testing code reflects that. I'm no sql expert, and I've never had to use CASE or functions, I'm used to stored procedures, but I can't use it

Comment: Which RDBMS? Syntax varies. I think you need the last version, but like this: `case @PreAQ when  0 then ...` (no =).

Comment: @Turophile, MS SQL2012. I also tried that way and get the same type of errors ( I did leave out the = sign )

Comment: Ah, SQL-Server? Then you need `something = CASE WHEN x=y THEN a WHEN x=w THEN b ELSE c END`. In your simple example, it would be easier to SET a variable `@match` and use a single SQL statement `select * from Contacts where ContactTitle like @match`.

Comment: @Turophile, I made an edit and showed what I am trying to do at work, the only thing different with this is that its still using the NorthWind as a test, so the filters and tables will be different that what I posted.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to create the inline table-valued function you can use something like this:

```
create function dbo.ufn_SomeFunction(@PreAQ int)
  returns table
return 
(select * from Contacts
  where (case when @PreAQ = 0 then CompanyName else ContactTitle end)
     LIKE (case when @PreAQ = 0 then 'An%' else 'S%' end) )
```

Notice, that you will have the table/clustered index scan.

Comment: I see where you are going with this, but '@PreAQ' will range from 0 - 2, and depending on which number '@PreAQ' is that will determine the filters on the table. 0 would have 5 filters, 1 will have 7 filters and 2 will have 12 filters being applied. Maybe i should edit my question and post the "live" function that i am working on instead of testing code?

Comment: I can't even post the code, its at work..So i am stuck with the testing code

Answer (score 0):

If your SQL statement can vary this much, you may need to use dynamic SQL, executed with `SP_EXECUTESQL`. See this SO question for an example: [Dynamic SQL Server stored procedure](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2593234/dynamic-sql-server-stored-procedure)

Comment: If you're suggesting that I use a stored procedure, forgive me if I'm wrong (because from the link, it looks like a stored procedure), I wish that I could then I wouldn't be having an issue. Its a function that I have to create

Answer (score 0):

This should work, but I agree Dynamic SQL would be a better approach.

```
    declare @PreAQ int
    set @PreAQ = 1

    select *
    from Contacts
    where (
            CompanyName like case @PreAQ
            when 0 then 'An%'
            end
         or ContactTitle like case @PreAQ
            when 1 then 'S%'
            end
          )
```

Answer (score 0):

In SQLServer's TSQL, [CASE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms181765.aspx) is not a programming construct for controlling which piece of code gets executed, but an [expression](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-au/library/ms190286.aspx) that always returns a single data value.

Try [IF...ELSE](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933214%28v=sql.80%29.aspx).

```
if @PreAQ = 0
   select * from Contacts where CompanyName like 'An%'
else if @PreAQ = 1
   select * from Contacts where ContactTitle like 'S%'
```

Comment: I tried using IF statements but it never worked in a function, however I do a have a solution for this and will be posting it later today, a couple different solutions.